# How to read each field of an line via batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a file which contents is as follows

```
 Testing:TEST1
 --- Import
 --- Build
 Testing:TEST2
 --- Import
 --- Build
 Testing:TEST3
 --- Import
 --- Build
Summary: Tests: 3 Failures:1
```

I needs to get the figures 3 and 1 .

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Windows >= 2000 for this?
If so, assuming data is in a file named "dump.txt", you could try creating a batch file (i.e. "foo.bat") containing this code:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=1,3,5 delims=: " %%A IN (dump.txt) DO (
   IF "%%A"=="Summary" echo %%B %%C
)
```

The batch file (foo.bat) and the data file (dump.txt) must be in the same folder.

[More information on "FOR /F" usage](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfortokens.php).

Comment: Neat. Much shorter than my solution ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill: You honor me. Thanks for the appreciation, I respect you :-)

Answer (score 0):

#### I need to get the figures 3 and 1

Use the following batch command (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* skip=2" %%i in ('find "Summary" %1') do  (
  set _line=%%i
  for /f "tokens=3,4" %%j in ("!_line!") do (
    set _tests=%%j
    set _temp=%%k
    set _fails=!_temp:~-1!
    echo Number of tests: !_tests!
    echo Number of fails: !_fails!
    )
  )
```

Usage:

```
test File
```

Where:

- File is the data file (`%1`)

Example:

```
F:\test>type test.txt
Testing:TEST1
 --- Import
 --- Build
 Testing:TEST2
 --- Import
 --- Build
 Testing:TEST3
 --- Import
 --- Build
Summary: Tests: 3 Failures:1

F:\test>test test.txt
Number of tests: 3
Number of fails: 1
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) - Extract part of a variable (substring)